# Overlapping TCustomControl objects draw out of order when the form is created/restored

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm having issues getting a TCustomControl to work with transparency in Delphi 2007.  I've currently reduced the problem to the code below.  The issue is that when the form is initially created the controls are drawing in the reverse order they are added to the form.  When the form is resized, they paint in the correct order.  What am I doing wrong? Excluding 3rd party solutions is there a more appropriate path to follow?

[image: Screen shot of the sample program after resizing the window]

Here's my sample project demonstrating the issue in Delphi 2007.

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Forms, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Messages,
  ExtCtrls;

type
  // Example of a TWinControl derived control
  TMyCustomControl = class(TCustomControl)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
      message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    YellowBox: TMyCustomControl;
    GreenBox: TMyCustomControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Windows, Graphics;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.OnPaint := FormPaint;

  GreenBox := TMyCustomControl.Create(self);
  GreenBox.Parent := self;
  GreenBox.SetBounds(10,10,200,200);
  GreenBox.color := clGreen;

  YellowBox := TMyCustomControl.Create(self);
  YellowBox.Parent := self;
  YellowBox.SetBounds(100,100,200,200);
  YellowBox.color := clYellow;

end;

// Paint bars on form background
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  for Idx := 0 to ClientHeight div 8 do
  begin
    if Odd(Idx) then
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite
    else
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;  // pale yellow
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, Idx * 8, ClientWidth, Idx * 8 + 8));
  end;
end;

{ TMyCustomControl }

procedure TMyCustomControl.CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  params.ExStyle := params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

procedure TMyCustomControl.WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
begin
  SetBkMode (msg.DC, TRANSPARENT);
  msg.result := 1;
end;

procedure TMyCustomControl.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := color;
  Canvas.RoundRect(0,0,width,height,50,50);
end;



end.
```

Comment: Try to derive your control from [TCustomTransparentControl](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TCustomTransparentControl.html) if you want to have transparent controls.

Comment: @Victoria, The transparency works as you can see from the image.  The drawing sequence is screwy.

Comment: I was about to tell you about Y, I understood X.. (I would use `TCustomTransparentControl` personally, because it invalidates underneath controls and well, is for transparent controls)

Comment: @Victoria, tried your suggestion of inheriting from TCustomTransparentControl... same results.  The last control added (YellowBox) is drawn below GreenBox.

Comment: Paint only with `TCustomTransparentControl` (nothing more, no `CreateParams` nor `WM_ERASEBKGND` message handling).

Comment: @Victoria, Sorry, what do you mean?  If change my code to have MyCustomControl inherit from TCustomTransparentControl and remove the procedures CreateParams & WMEraseBkGnd, how is that different?  Is TMyCustomControl.Paint not the right place to be painting?

Comment: Let's put it this way: I've never ever ever had a reason to handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, and I've written many custom controls with their own 100% pure painting. I've also done some transparent ones without having to inherit exclusively from the `TCustomTransparentControl`. Try using *only* your `Paint` procedure and see if that helps. Not saying they're useless, but start small and work your way up to the point where things start failing.

Comment: @Jerry,  inherited from `TCustomTransparentControl`, remove the procedures `CreateParams` & `WMEraseBkGnd` with the same results of incorrect drawing order.

Comment: In the past, I recall abandoning any attempt at true "transparency", and instead chose to draw the parent's background on the control. What happens when you inherit from `TCustomControl` or `TCustomWinControl`?

Comment: While debugging, I can see the YellowBox being drawn first. I don't seen how drawing the background on the control will help that situation.  My sample code already inherits from `TCustomControl` which inherits from `TWinControl`.  I can't find that a `TCustomWinControl` class exists as you suggested.  When subclassing `TCustomControl`  I need to override `CreateParams` to add `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to `ExStyle` or the background will not be transparent.

Comment: Of course, `Paint` is the right place. I haven't said otherwise. The major point is that you have no control over which control is painted first. That's upon OS. If OS needs to repaint certain screen rectangle, it asks intersecting windows to do their painting. `TCustomTransparentControl` sanitize that simply by calling `InvalidateControlsUnderneath` before its painting starts (that way it repaints also what's behind the control). That's the whole magic.

Comment: Very good MCVE in the first post.

Comment: Thought of posting an answer but figured it won't be very convincing, hence a comment... The problem is with the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flags, not of z-order. Contrary to expectations, sibling windows/controls do not receive `WM_PAINT` [always] in a bottom to top order. What preserves visual z-order is the update regions (`WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`). A *transparent* control cannot employ an update region, it always paints over non-transparent siblings. Summary: transparent controls are not meant to be siblings.

Comment: The comments have been pretty misleading until Sertac arrived

Comment: What's misleading on suggesting `TCustomTransparentControl`? Or saying that control painting is not under your control?

Comment: @sertac, sounds like an answer. I can accept that reality and refactor accordingly.

Comment: @Victoria, I guess what's misleading is the first part; `TCustomTransparentControl` cannot help with the problem for the reason I briefly explained, also as verified by the poster in the comments. If anything, using `TCustomTransparentControl` as ancestor will do more harm than good, you will not even be able to `Invalidate` your control and have it drawn above the other one. That's because, as you've stated, a CustomTransparentControl also invalidates the one *underneath* and so you're in square one. You can test and check all these by yourself of course..

Comment: @c0p - Done....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is wrong is your expectancy of the order of painting of your controls. The order of controls receiving `WM_PAINT` messages is documented to be actually in the exact opposite order, the top-most control receives the message first. More on the documentation later, since having `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` styled siblings leaves us in undocumented territory. As you have already noted, you have a case where the order of the controls receiving `WM_PAINT` messages is not deterministic - when resizing the window the order changes.

I've modified a bit of your reproduction case to see what is happening. The modifications are the inclusion of two panels and a debug output when they receive `WM_PAINT`.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Forms, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Messages, ExtCtrls;

type
  TMyCustomControl = class(TCustomControl)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
      message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  end;

  TPanel = class(extctrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    YellowBox: TMyCustomControl;
    GreenBox: TMyCustomControl;
    Panel1, Panel2: TPanel;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  sysutils, windows, graphics;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Width := 590;
  Height := 270;
  OnPaint := FormPaint;

  GreenBox := TMyCustomControl.Create(self);
  GreenBox.Parent := self;
  GreenBox.SetBounds(20, 20, 140, 140);
  GreenBox.color := clGreen;
  GreenBox.Name := 'GreenBox';
//{
  Panel1 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel1.Parent := Self;
  Panel1.SetBounds(240, 40, 140, 140);
  Panel1.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel1.Color := clMoneyGreen;
  Panel1.Name := 'Panel1';

  Panel2 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel2.Parent := Self;
  Panel2.SetBounds(260, 60, 140, 140);
  Panel2.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel2.Color := clCream;
  Panel2.Name := 'Panel2';
//}
  YellowBox := TMyCustomControl.Create(self);
  YellowBox.Parent := self;
  YellowBox.SetBounds(80, 80, 140, 140);
  YellowBox.color := clYellow;
  YellowBox.Name := 'YellowBox';
  YellowBox.BringToFront;
end;

// Paint bars on form background
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  for Idx := 0 to ClientHeight div 8 do
  begin
    if Odd(Idx) then
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite
    else
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;  // pale yellow
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, Idx * 8, ClientWidth, Idx * 8 + 8));
  end;
end;

{ TPanel }

procedure TPanel.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format(' %s painting..', [Name])));
  inherited;
end;

{ TMyCustomControl }

procedure TMyCustomControl.CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  params.ExStyle := params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

procedure TMyCustomControl.WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
begin
  msg.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TMyCustomControl.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format(' %s painting..', [Name])));
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyCustomControl.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Canvas.RoundRect(0, 0, Width, Height, 50, 50);
end;

end.
```

Which produces this form:

[image]

As determined by order of creation, the z-order is, from bottom to top,

1. GreenBox,
2. Panel1,
3. Panel2,
4. YellowBox.

The debug output for the `WM_PAINT` messages is this:

> ```
> Debug Output:  Panel2 painting.. Process Project1.exe (12548)
> Debug Output:  Panel1 painting.. Process Project1.exe (12548)
> Debug Output:  YellowBox painting.. Process Project1.exe (12548)
> Debug Output:  GreenBox painting.. Process Project1.exe (12548)
> ```

There are two things worth to note in this order.

**First**, Panel2 receives the paint message before Panel1, although Panel2 is higher in the z-order.

So how is it that while we see Panel2 as a whole, but we see only part of Panel1 even though it is painted later? This is where update regions come into play. The [`WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) style flags in controls tell the OS that part of a control occupied by a sibling higher in the z-order is not going to be painted.

> Clips child windows relative to each other; that is, when a particular
>   child window receives a **WM_PAINT** message, the **WS_CLIPSIBLINGS**
>   style clips all other overlapping child windows out of the region of
>   the child window to be updated.

Let's dig into a bit more in the `WM_PAINT` handler of Panel1 and see how the OS' update region looks like.

```
{ TPanel }

// not declared in D2007
function GetRandomRgn(hdc: HDC; hrgn: HRGN; iNum: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    external gdi32;
const
  SYSRGN = 4;

procedure TPanel.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PS: TPaintStruct;
  Rgn: HRGN;

  TestDC: HDC;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format(' %s painting..', [Name])));

  Message.DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
  Rgn := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (Name = 'Panel1') and (GetRandomRgn(Message.DC, Rgn, SYSRGN) = 1) then begin
    OffsetRgn(Rgn, - Form1.ClientOrigin.X + Width + 40, - Form1.ClientOrigin.Y);
    TestDC := GetDC(Form1.Handle);
    SelectObject(TestDC, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    PaintRgn(TestDC, Rgn);
    ReleaseDC(Form1.Handle, TestDC);
    DeleteObject(Rgn);
  end;
  inherited;
  EndPaint(Handle, PS);
end;
```

The `BeginPaint` will clip the update region with the system update region which you can then retrieve with `GetRandomRgn`. I've dumped the clipped update region to the right of the form. Don't mind the `Form1` references or missing error checks, we are only debugging. Anyway, this produces the below form:

[image]

So, whatever you draw in the client area of Panel1, it will get clipped into the black shape, hence it cannot be visually come into front of Panel2.

**Second**, remember that the green box is created first, then the panels and then the yellow last. So why is it that the two transparent controls are painted after the two panels?

First, remember that controls are painted from top to bottom. Now, how can it be possible for a transparent control to draw onto something which is drawn after it? Obviously it is not possible. So the entire painting algorithm have to change. There is no documentation on this and the best explanation I've found is from a [blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121217-00/?p=5823) of Raymond Chen:

> ... The `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended window style alters the painting
>   algorithm as follows: If a `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` window needs to be
>   painted, and it has any non-`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` windows siblings (which
>   belong to the same process) which also need to be painted, then the
>   window manager will paint the non-`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` windows first.

The top to bottom painting order makes it a difficult one when you have transparent controls. Then there is the case of overlapping transparent controls - which is more transparent than the other? Just accept the fact that overlapping transparent controls produce undetermined behavior.

If you investigate the system update regions of the transparent boxes in the above test case, you'll find both to be exact squares.

Let's shift the panels to in-between the boxes.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Width := 590;
  Height := 270;
  OnPaint := FormPaint;

  GreenBox := TMyCustomControl.Create(self);
  GreenBox.Parent := self;
  GreenBox.SetBounds(20, 20, 140, 140);
  GreenBox.color := clGreen;
  GreenBox.Name := 'GreenBox';
//{
  Panel1 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel1.Parent := Self;
  Panel1.SetBounds(40, 40, 140, 140);
  Panel1.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel1.Color := clMoneyGreen;
  Panel1.Name := 'Panel1';

  Panel2 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel2.Parent := Self;
  Panel2.SetBounds(60, 60, 140, 140);
  Panel2.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel2.Color := clCream;
  Panel2.Name := 'Panel2';
//}
  YellowBox := TMyCustomControl.Create(self);
  YellowBox.Parent := self;
  YellowBox.SetBounds(80, 80, 140, 140);
  YellowBox.color := clYellow;
  YellowBox.Name := 'YellowBox';
  YellowBox.BringToFront;
end;

 ...

procedure TMyCustomControl.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PS: TPaintStruct;
  Rgn: HRGN;

  TestDC: HDC;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format(' %s painting..', [Name])));

  Message.DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
  Rgn := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (Name = 'GreenBox') and (GetRandomRgn(Message.DC, Rgn, SYSRGN) = 1) then begin
    OffsetRgn(Rgn, - Form1.ClientOrigin.X + Width + 260, - Form1.ClientOrigin.Y);
    TestDC := GetDC(Form1.Handle);
    SelectObject(TestDC, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    PaintRgn(TestDC, Rgn);
    ReleaseDC(Form1.Handle, TestDC);
    DeleteObject(Rgn);
  end;
  inherited;
  EndPaint(Handle, PS);
end;
```

[image]

The right-most black shape is the system update region for the GreenBox. After all the system can apply clipping to a transparent control. I think it would suffice to conclude that the painting algorithm is not perfect when you've got a bunch of transparent controls.

---

As promised, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183426(v=vs.85).aspx) quote for the `WM_PAINT` order. One reason I've left this to last is that it includes a possible solution (of course we already found one solution, scatter some non-transparent controls in-between your transparent controls):

> ... If a window in the parent chain is composited (a window with
>   WX_EX_COMPOSITED), sibling windows receive WM_PAINT messages in the
>   reverse order of their position in the Z order. Given this, the window
>   highest in the Z order (on the top) receives its **WM_PAINT** message
>   last, and vice versa. If a window in the parent chain is not
>   composited, sibling windows receive **WM_PAINT** messages in Z order.

For as little as I tested, setting `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` on the parent form seems to work. But I don't know if it is applicable in your case.

Comment: Adding the style `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` does indeed work for `TCustomControl` in the original sample code above.  For the curious, it does not work for controls derived from `TCustomTransparentControl`.  The controls paint in the expected order, but the transparency is lost.